# net core handling form submitting in two validation ways

Tags: validation, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm using razor page to build my application
and i'm stucking with a situation in form validation that is : 
i have create a one page that contains many input fields,
one of them is mobile number
and for this field it should be **maximum 10 digits** and it is **required**,

and for that form, there are two buttons,
one is for submitting the form only if all the fields is valid,
and the second button is for **'save for later'**, here also all fields must be valid
except the required attribute it's optional,
i mean for mobile number field, it's okay if it is empty but it should display an error if it exceed 10 digits.

i know i can use different pages with different view models and validation
but i want to handle it in one page.

so what is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can help me to give a better answer if you share your model and controllers.
But at first touch, I think you have to remove the `Required` attribute for the `MobileNumber` field because it supposes to be `nullable` in your database.

After removing the `Required` attribute, try to handle the null check manually in your first scenario, you have a bunch of solutions, and one of the simple solutions is using `if` and throwing an `exception` or using `FluentValidation`.